# Where is the official documentation for chmod?

Tags: linux, unix, gnu, chmod

I would have expected it to be here in the [gnu documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html) but it is not.

So I [Googled it](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=chmod%20documentation) and their were many links but I don't know which one is the most "official".

For example the first hit is for an Ubuntu distribution, and the second is for a Mac OS X distribution.

Comment: Are you talking about the `chmod(1)` command or the `chmod(2)` system call?

Comment: Your `gnu documentation` link is just the `bash` manual. `chmod` isn't part of `bash`, it's a separate program.

Comment: @Barmar Given that the OP's "gnu documentation" link leads to Bash manual, it is reasonably safe to assume that `chmod` refers to `chmod(1)`.

Comment: @user4815162342 Yeah, I posted my first comment before I noticed that link.

Comment: How about `man chmod` in your terminal?

Comment: Maybe not 100%, but it's still a reasonable question to ask. The question is tagged Linux, and the majority of Linux systems (at least those that expose a `chmod` to the user, unlike say Android environments) do share the `chmod` implementation, and that implementation does have a canonical place where it's documented online. Of course, the best place to look for documentation is always the particular OS/distribution itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On a typical Linux system, the `chmod` command comes from the [GNU coreutils](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/coreutils.html) package, and its canonical documentation is provided [on their site](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/chmod-invocation.html#chmod-invocation).

Some Linux distributions can pick a different `chmod` (e.g. to fit on a small installation medium), in which case the documentation should be available via the `man` command or as part of the distribution's documentation. Likewise, the documentation for Mac OS commands is available both as man pages and on [Apple's developer site](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/).

Answer (score 1):

The Linux man-pages project is housed at [man7.org](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/index.html). The `chmod(1)` documentation is at http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/chmod.1.html

Comment: Barmar you like talking to yourself don't ya? Jokes aside, please, don't delete comments.

Comment: @black Apparently the OP deleted all his comments that I was responding to.